# Invalid country code when using directory.customers.update

Tags: google-directory-api

When I call: directory.customers.update with the following info

customerKey: ......

```
body:
{
"customerDomain": "mydomain.fr",
 "alternateEmail": "john.doe@mydomain.be",
 "postalAddress": {
    "contactName": "John Doe",
    "organizationName": "My Domain",
    "countryCode": "FR"
 } 
}
I get {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid country code"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid country code"
 }
}
```

and this, whatever the country code is

Comment: Any update on this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing country code is not possible with grandfathered G Suite accounts other than when upgrading to paid version.

Comment: Actually, change is not possible even when upgrading to paid version. Country assignment has been frozen sometime in 2015. I recall I was still able to change country codes in late 2014.